# How to get thread title using praw?

Tags: python, praw

I'm using praw to write a bot for reddit. I already know how to use the get_comments() function to get all the comments in a subreddit. However, I would like to get the titles of all the posts in a subreddit, however, after going through the docs for praw, I could not find a function which does so.

I just want to go into a subreddit, and fetch all the titles of the posts, and then store them in an object.

Could someone tell me how I go around achieving this?

Answer (score 3):

```
import praw

r=praw.Reddit('demo')
subreddit=r.get_subreddit('stackoverflow')

for submission in subreddit.get_hot(limit=10):
    print submission.title
```

This information is available in the [PRAW documentation](http://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/writing_a_bot.html).

Comment: Doesn't that only get titles in the hot list?

Comment: @FlameDra It will grab the first 10 posts in the subreddit, sorted by "hot". You have to provide a sorting method. Additionally, there is a limit of 1000 so you cannot grab more than 1000 posts. If you want to grab every post ever made in a subreddit, it is simply not possible through the reddit API.

Comment: How do I get x amount of posts from the subreddit? Where I can define x and x can be less than 1000.

Comment: change `limit=10` to `limit=X`

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty late but anyways you can go through the official reddit api JSON responses format. From there you can see all the attributes that are available to you for a particular object.

[Here's the github link for the reddit API](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/JSON)

Edit: You can also use `pprint(vars(object_name))`